# Error occurs when using cocoapods?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I am using a library called MZFormSheetController, and I put it in to my program using cocoapods ,when the app runs ,it tell me there's error in the library.
[image]

[image]

I seems it cannot recognize the UIViewController? what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing UIKit framework import. You have to @import UIKit;